# Where can I find arguments for options class for geckodriver?

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I am using selenium with Python and firefox browser, I am trying to download a file and **disable** the pop up window that asks if I want to save it and where:
[image]

Since FirefoxProfile and FirefoxOptions and deprecated in selenium 4.0.0 + , I am trying to use the Options() class to replace it

There are various arguments to be given to the option class, such as:

```
        options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
```

But I need the argument to disable the download window I attached above.
I searched a lot and I can't find any documentation on the possible arguments you can pass to options.add_argument .

I've tried down grading to earlier version and add FirefoxProfile arguments such as:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")
```

But it still doesn't work.

If any one can share a documentation specifying the possible arguments for options, or just the specific argument to disable this pop up - that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use Selenium beta version ?

Comment: Not really. But as I mentioned FirefoxProfile.set_preference doesn't work as well. If there is a way to achieve this using an older version it I don't mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have these preferences set in my framework and it works good so far

```py
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.msexcel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,text/plain,text/x-csv,application/x-csv,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values,data:text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/xml,text/plain,text/xml,image/jpeg,application/octet-stream,data:text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/csv,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.msexcel,text/anytext,text/comma-separated-values,text/csv,text/plain,text/x-csv,application/x-csv,text/x-comma-separated-values,text/tab-separated-values,data:text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/xml,text/plain,text/xml,image/jpeg,application/octet-stream,data:text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
profile.set_preference("dom.file.createInChild", True)
```

Possibly most of these settings will be redundant for you, but they may appear useful in the future.